# Typescript :: Related Generic Constraints

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, typescript2.0, react-typescript

In `React`, I have a generic interface like so:

```
interface BaseProps<T> {
  data: T;
}
```

The consumers of my code will extend this to define their own `Props` and `Component`:

```
interface MyProps extends BaseProps<string> {
  ...
}
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyProps> = ({ data }) => {
  ...
}
```

I want to write a method that accepts such a component and returns a value of the same type as `MyComponent.data`. This is what I'm struggling with. I'm trying to write this method and invoke it as:

```
function myFunc<T, U extends BaseProps<T>>(component: React.FC<U>): T {
  return ...
}
const ret1 = myFunc(MyComponent);
const ret2 = myFunc<string, MyProps>(MyComponent);
```

`ret2` has the correct type `string` but `ret` comes out to have `unknown` type. Is there a way I can enforce constraints in the `myFunc` method such that `ret1` is typed correctly without requiring me to explicitly declare types in `<>`?

## Update

Both @futut and @proton have given (almost) identical solution that clearly work in this case! Kudos!

However, the sample code I wrote here was a bit over-simplified. If I change the `BaseProps` interface to:

```
interface BaseProps<T> {
  callback: (value: T) => void;
}
```

Then I can no longer use `U["data"]`. Is there a way to be able to return a value of the type of `value` parameter in `MyComponent.callback` in this case?

PS: Apologies for shifting the goalpost here. My bad at oversimplifying too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just explicitly inform typescript, that type of `BaseProps.data` is going to be function return value, like below:

```js
function myFunc<T, U extends BaseProps<T>>(component: React.FC<U>): U['data'] {
  ...
}
```

That way you won't have to pass types to generic statement (`<>`), as long as your component passed to `myFunc` is typed properly.

---

Edit:
Regarding second version of question:
Things get tricky here. You can point to value of a callback by using `infer` keyword like below:

```js
function myFunc<T extends BaseProps<any>>(
  component: React.FC<T>,
): T['callback'] extends (a: infer R) => void ? R : never {
...
```

Check documentation regarding that keyword:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

Comment: Hi @proton! Thanks for responding. This works! And thanks for introducing me to the `infer` keyword. Marking this as the correct solution. Thanks again! =)

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't know that the type `U` provided can also tell it what `T` is. You could instead use a single type parameter and use an indexed access to get the type of its `data` property:

```
function myFunc<T extends BaseProps<any>>(component: React.FC<T>): T["data"] { 
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Comment: Hi @futur! Thanks for responding. Could you please have a look at the edit to the question?