# Returning type based on a string parameter used as keyof a Record type

Tags: typescript

I have state type as follows

```js
type RootState = {
    car: Car[],    
    user: User[],
    driver: Driver[],
}

const state: RootState = {
    car: [{name: "Car1", brand: "Ford"}, {name: "Car2", brand: "Chevvy"}],
    driver: [{name: "joe", age: "3"}, {name: "carl", age: "4"}],
    user: [{name: "Hank", money: 1300}]
}
```

I am writing a method that accepts the name as the first parameter and on the basis of the given name, it determines the return type automatically.

It should know that if it is given car as the first parameter, `state[type]` would be an array of Cars and thus, should return a car

```js
function getResourceAtIndex(type: keyof RootState, index: number){
    return state[type][index]
}

const car = getResourceAtIndex("car", 0)//Return types is Car |User|Driver instead of just car
```

```js
type Car= {
    name: string,
    brand: string,
}
type User= {
    name: string,money: number
}
type Driver= {
    name: string, age: string
}
type RootState ={
    car: Car[],    
    user: User[],
    driver: Driver[],


}

const state: RootState = {
    car: [{name: "Car1", brand: "Ford"}, {name: "Car2", brand: "Chevvy"}],
    driver: [{name: "joe", age: "3"}, {name: "carl", age: "4"}],
    user: [{name: "Hank", money: 1300}]
}
function getResourceAtIndex<R>(type: keyof RootState, index: number){
    return state[type][index]
}
const car = getResourceAtIndex("car", 0)
```

Comment: This is likely to be a fairly straightforward generic function, but your `RootState` has a typo and refers to three undeclared types. Could you make the code a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?

Comment: I'd say [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0Vjw) is how to proceed, unless you have some kind of problem with it (and assuming my definitions of your undeclared types are correct).  Does that work for you? If so I'm happy to write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I've produced a SSCE

Comment: jcalz thanks.  it works. Maybe post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: `type RootState {` is invalid syntax.  I know what you mean, but it's always recommended to pass example code through an IDE before you post it, so that nobody has to spend time or effort fixing problems you don't actually have before getting to the problem you do have.

Comment: its strange. I have the correct one in my ide, but somehow managed to copy it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the type checker to keep track of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the argument you pass in for the `type` parameter to `getResourceAsIndex`, then you need a more specific type than `keyof RootState`.  To do so, you probably want to make that function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `state`, where `K` is [constrained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72426760/typescript-related-generic-constraints) to `keyof RootState`:

```
function getResourceAtIndex<K extends keyof RootState>(
    type: K, index: number
): RootState[K][number] {
    return state[type][index]
}
```

You also need to [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) of the function as `RootState[K][number]` to explicitly say you'd like a generic [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) type as opposed to the inferred `RootState[keyof RootState][number]`.

Now things work as you want:

```
const car = getResourceAtIndex("car", 0);
// const car: Car
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=34&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGf5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwBo8CAjKOEAEwutpDpwBfHDlCRYiFAFVK0bM3xFSPGvSYFkxAPYgIATwogArsRbQhIsdHhJkAEVoA3Obg1LyVVf3UE4dD7xqFjhgegAOKABKWlpgAMpgcJDIALzyGggYFOhQANoAuj74RrJQFDLQBUXInE7QFA7AznmFwQg61J5JHtGxCd2p6QSZZci5WIQkHgBEOQCM0wzIbBzcyNMAYlpQnNPIgksT7hSzGABMi8vsXCeoABYQjo56e4KtGrVN9WNHUycAVloIJc-DMAMyvQ6TZTrEYAGxB-hOABZXu8CCVvuNoTMABIcADWl20ugMyDmYIADJT9vlgjAjCAEGBgDpkP4wJEIJQtEYoEgAIJgACSXAgAA8ADwAaWQEsgXEoyAJ+i0MGQvXiiUgAD4ABQKZChCIUaVLUCcCWGExmKA4ACUFE1-UguWl+VyxlM0HyQ3wUAgYD5IC6ruNEA9FoldOEOHaIE6I0GHK5PL5gpFYvFeumI0ulPtAG4cAB6EvIeOJrJoDA4IA)