# How to define a function which only accepts parameters which may be a type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to define a function like:

```
function isNumber(param: ???): param is number {
}
```

If the param may be a number, e.g. `number | string`, `number | boolean`, it can be passed to the function. If not, e.g. its type is `string` or `boolean`, there will be compilation errors.

Is it possible to define such a type?

Comment: Why `param` and `obj`?

Comment: @jcalz Good catch, thanks!

Comment: TS doesn't have lower bounded generics so you need to emulate them... does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDyr1m) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! That's perfect and is just what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually you want to make `isNumber()` generic in the type `T` of `param`, but you want `T` to be *lower bounded* by `number`.  This is the opposite of the normal `extends` [constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72426760/typescript-related-generic-constraints) which is considered an *upper bound*.  Unfortunately TypeScript does not support lower bounded generics directly.  This is requested in  [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520), and if it's ever implemented it might use `super` instead of `extends` and look like

```
// NOT VALID TS (as of 4.7), DON'T DO THIS
function isNumber<T super number>(param: T): param is number {
  return typeof param === "number"
}
```

But, as I said, we can't do this.

---

Instead we can kind of emulate lower bounded generics by using a regular upper bound on a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  Something like `T extends (U extends T ? unknown : never)` will behave somewhat like `T super U`.  If `T` is a supertype of `U`, then `(U extends T ? unknown : never)` evaluates to `unknown`, and so the constraint (`T extends unknown`) is met.  Otherwise, `(U extends T ? unknown : never)` evaluates to `never`, and so the constraint (`T extends never`) is probably not met (unless `T` is `never` itself, which cannot be guarded against this way).

In your case we are actually fine if `T` is either a supertype or a subtype of `number`, so we can write `T extends (number extends T ? unknown : number)` and that way if `T` happens to be a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `14` everything still works.

A wrinkle is that the compiler doesn't understand that `param` is likely to be a supertype of `number`, so you can't return the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) `param is number`.  Instead you need to write a type that the compiler sees as assignable to `T` (and `number`).  So we'll use the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `param is T & number`.

So here it is:

```
function isNumber<T extends number extends T ? unknown : number>(
  param: T
): param is number & T {
  return typeof param === "number"
}
```

And let's test it:

```
isNumber("oops"); // error, Argument of type 'string' is 
// not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
isNumber(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : 123); // okay
isNumber(14); // okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAegVABKIQcg8gFQgNQIIBkCSARCiBlAGgh3lgHJkz8AJLA4AMwFcA7AYwBcBLAezYQeAZ1gsAtgCMApgCcAPMmEsADnIhsJM2QD4AFCoCGsw+IBc+AJQWjJ8UOEat6gN7AIEWdK4tZgrgCeanxMELamEAC80RAARJpScrHAAL7AYCDAWaycvAIOYokKyNIAHlzSbAAmjgnaEGUV1Y7IAPwQ7ADWbHwA7oIWdXL67mHGphaIwNZjdg5ORRAAZPgQbh5ePn4QgcGh4fbRkXFDsslpWSKF2nqxfHwqwrGWANwQIDBysnyyJGiyAHMJJUuBAQjsgtIIBRhFxZDw2ACKPMeqDDMJhDwAWxDJIADZQrh8WambzqcG7KEUU4UAB0wCuzlkegAsoYuAALWkmap8cR6SwQeQQAAMtIArBB2rFcRxYhALABGABMAGZXu8YHxOoYAgzREy9IqACwaj5gnUBIA)

Comment: I found if I want to define a function `isNumberOrString(obj: ???)`, I have to write  `isNumberOrString<T extends (string extends T ? unknown : never) & (number extends T ? unknown : never)>(obj: T)`, is there any way to simplify it? I tried `isNumberOrString<T extends (string | number) extends T ? unknown : never)>(obj: T)` but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, not sure.  But a comments section isn't a great place to ask and answer followup questions.  For example I don't quite know what "it doesn't work" means; [they behave the same as far as I can see](https://tsplay.dev/N9nAJm)... a [mre] and full description of your issue would be helpful, but that really needs more space than you have here.   If you can't find your answer elsewhere you might want to post your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. The comment here actually is not what I meant to ask, and I just posted a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972026/how-to-define-a-function-which-doesnt-accept-null-undefined) . And thanks again for your help