# How to define a function which doesn't accept null/undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Thanks to @jcalz 's help, I made a function like this:

```
declare function isNotNil<T extends (null extends T ? never : unknown) & (undefined extends T ? never: unknown)>(
    param: T
  ): param is T;
```

It's working as expected as it will show an error if the parameter is null/undefined:

[image]

But I think if the definition can be simplified, e.g.

```
declare function isNotNil<T extends ((null | undefined) extends T ? never : unknown)>(
    param: T
  ): param is T;
```

Which doesn't work since it doesn't show any error for null/undefined arguments.

[image]

This is [a demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YyDeAoJSAmE8ANiAE7IBmArsPAC4CWA9sEg1AHJN0cNEA8AFSQQAHnQjA8UJAApgVIkRHjJ0pMID8SdADcIpJAC4kNANbAmAd2ABKJADI5NAhQbo8KiVJladEfVITc0sbWwA+WRxcJDhScBNBaNsTOPA2XwBuLGj2Lh4+eUUiW2zcPO5eIlkXCDcPUtzOSsKAIiYmGChWxvLmguq6UipkbQUlE1aQaZ6yjPyq2QBGABZGrABfLFBIWARkQSsmJGxcAmIyShp6ZlYKgaEvNRlZIqUkAB9TKTr3CDx7GJvOo-HoDMZvhZrHZItFcGkwIlkqkyOl2Bpsk0FoVxiU5vdFrV6v9evMWtV2p1uqSCYUhiMkGNipNpiBZljycs1tkNkA)

Comment: `(null | undefined) extends null` is false.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73069680/how-to-define-a-function-which-only-accepts-parameters-which-may-be-a-type-in-ty/73069921?noredirect=1#comment130604023_73069921

Comment: If you don't accept `null` and `undefined` to a function called `isNotNil`, then what is the point of this function since now it will always only return true?

Comment: @yqlim Thanks for pointing this out. The name is a fake simplified one, you can consider it something like `saveUser`

Comment: So are you just looking for [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/WzPy3N)?  If so I could write up an answer (but I'd suggest you [edit] the question to rename the function to something like `acceptNonNullable()` and have it return `void`, instead of the confusing type guard function whose job is apparently to always return `true`).  If not, what am I missing?  Either way, if you reply, please mention @jcalz in your comment to notify me.